# convert sqlalchemy response to pydantic object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

How to convert string to model type in FastAPI?
If I have Student model and want to convert string student to type model. How to convert it?

```py
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHAMY_DATABASE_URL,pool_pre_ping=True,pool_recycle=3600)
meta = MetaData()
con = engine.connect()
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


def convert_model(student,db:Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
   Q=student.all()



convert_model(student,db)
```

It's giving the error `str object has no attribute all()`

Comment: hello...I am sending records=db.query(StudentModel).all()  records=jsonable_encoder(records).  I am sending records to convert_model function and want to create dynamic query. convert_model(records,db:Session = Depends(database.get_db)...but its considerring records as string and not model

Comment: @M.K.S Also explain exactly what you are trying to solve.
"Converting a string student to a model student". What does that mean?
Does it mean that you have the name/id of a student, and you want to fetch the the student data from a table in the database?
Or do you have full student data in some string form, e..g JSON `{"name": "John Doe", age: 21, ....}` and you want to insert it into the database?
I really don't understand what you even want to do.

Comment: I just want to pass model to function and create dynamic query for API which has filter column and criteria in request and it will show matching data from model....e,g if in filter_column student name I am passing from request and criteria has xyz name then only that students data will be shown in GET call

Comment: So you pass the function some filter parameters, and want to retrieve all students from the database that match the given filters?
Just do it manually:
`query = session.query(StudentTable)
if filter.name is not None: query = query.filter(StudentTable.name == filter.name)
if filter.age is not None:  query = query.filter(StudentTable.age == filter.age)
return query.all()`

Answer (score 5):

In you example student is a definition parameter and not your database model.

you should take a look at [fastapi official user guid](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/)e, it explain in detail and in a simple manner how to build a simple yet clean api.

you have a [dedicated section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#sql-relational-databases) on how to load your db object.

you have a [dedicated section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response-model-return-type) on honw to handle list response from db models.

db_config.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base

from app.settings import get_settings

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHAMY_DATABASE_URL,pool_pre_ping=True,pool_recycle=3600)
meta = MetaData()
con = engine.connect()
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
Base = declarative_base()

def get_session():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

my_router.py

```py
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic import parse_obj_as

from db_config import get_session
from db_config import Base

class StudentModel(Base): # <- your database model
    something = Column(String)

class StudentSchema(BaseModel): # <- your pydantic model
    something: str = Field(..., example="something")

@app_router.get('/students', response_model=List[StudentSchema])
def get_all_StudentModel(session:Session = Depends(get_session)):
    return parse_obj_as(List[StudentSchema], session.query(StudentModel).all())
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way recommended by Pydantic is using `model_validate`. It's the more modern way of doing things, and is a nicer API than `parse_obj_as`.

```py
class StudentModel(Base): # <- your database model
    something = Column(String)

class StudentSchema(BaseModel): # <- your pydantic model
    something: str = Field(..., example="something")


results = []
for student in session.query(StudentModel).all():
    results.append(StudentSchema.model_validate(student)
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/blog/pydantic-v2/#model-namespace-cleanup

[image: Pydantic docs]